# Unix command to find files which are olden than N days, convert to zip and move to s3

Tags: unix, amazon-s3

UNIX COMMAND -I want to find files which are older than N days and convert it into respective zip format and than move than zip to amazon s3.

Comment: no single command available to do that ,write a script to do that ..

Comment: you have sudo coded your own work, but try to show what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

This will build your archive

```
tar --remove-files -czf mytar.gz $(find . -type f -mtime +2)
```